# Why does my YQL query return a null result in jQuery while the same YQL query returns positive at the YQL console?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, yql

Suppose I have a YQL query like this (in fact, this is the exact query I'm using):

```
select * from xml where url="http://blog.artbeads.com/feed/"
                  and itemPath="//rss/channel/item"
```

[Run this query on the YQL Console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=%20SELECT%20%2a%20FROM%20xml%20WHERE%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fblog.artbeads.com%2Ffeed%2F%22%20and%20itemPath%3D%22%2F%2Frss%2Fchannel%2Fitem%22) and it should return 10 items.

Now consider the following jQuery (which is nearly the exact code I'm using for production, except for the success call, but I don't believe that to be an important factor):

```
// Working example at http://jsbin.com/ekomi4
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  data: {
    q: 'select * from xml where url="http://blog.artbeads.com/feed/" and itemPath="//rss/channel/item"',
    format: 'json'
  },
  success: function(content) { $('#content').text(JSON.stringify(content, null, ' ')) }
})
```

The above code is not performing as expected: a JSON object is returned (as expected), but `query.results` = `null` (unexpected).

Comment: try using curl -v, or wget to get debug info about the request

Answer (score 0):

I followed the jsbin link, and everything works fine in Chrome running on Windows. You should verify that the current browser actually supports the `JSON.stringify` method, and if it doesn't, use a library (https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/).

Comment: I've updated the original question for clarity, which has nothing to do with the functionality of `JSON.stringify`, but rather what was returned by the `$.ajax()` call. Thanks for the comment, in any case.